# XML Parsing using JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, xml, xpath

Here's an XML snippet:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="val1" value="val2"/>
```

The XML document is loaded in memory, ready to be parsed.

How would you get and write the value of "val2" to the web page?

Thanks,
rodchar

Post Comments:
**I'm getting .selectSingleNode is not a function:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
        xhttp=new window.XMLHttpRequest()
      }
    else
      {
        xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
      }
    xhttp.open("GET","test.xml",false);
    xhttp.send("");
    xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;

    var node = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("/appSettings/add[@key='Key']");
    alert(node.getAttribute("value"));


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery, it's so much nicer.

```
  $(request.responseXML).find("add").each(function() {
      var marker = $(this);
      var key = marker.attr("key");
      var value = marker.attr("value");
  });
```

Comment: how would i get the value "val2" (see O.P.)?

Comment: value would be val2, marker.attr accesses the value for some key. The OP is a bit confusing in this regard because the naming overlaps with this terminology. marker.attr("value") will return "val2"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var node = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("/appSettings/add[@key='val1']");
alert(node.getAttribute("value"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var xmlDoc;
if (typeof DOMParser !== 'undefined') {
  xmlDoc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(xmlText, 'text/xml');
} else {
  xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
  xmlDoc.async = 'false';
  xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlText);
}
```